# Nodejs/MongoDB: Push dynamically created object into array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to push objects into array using mongodb and nodejs.
My word schema is:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const wordSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  ugrWordCyr: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  ugrWordArb: {
    type: String
  },
  rusTranslation: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  examples: [
    {
      exCyr: { type: String },
      trRus: { type: String },
      exLat: { type: String },
      trEng: { type: String },
      exArab: { type: String }
    }
  ],
  origin: {
    type: String
  },
  sphere: {
    type: String
  },
  see: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  lexis: {
    type: String
  },
  grammar: {
    type: String
  },
  partOfSpeech: {
    type: String
  },
  style: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = Word = mongoose.model("words", wordSchema);
```

As you can see there is the example array in the schema. It is needed to be fulled with dynamically created objects. So in my words api I am doing this thing, but it does not work.

```
// @route  POST api/words
// @desc   Add words to profile
// @access Private
router.post(
  '/',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateWordInput(req.body);

    // Check validation
    if (!isValid) {
      // Return any errors
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    Word.find({}).then(word => {
      if (
        word.filter(
          wrd =>
            wrd.ugrWordCyr.toString().toLowerCase() ===
            req.body.ugrWordCyr.toLowerCase()
        ).length !== 0
      ) {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({ wordalreadyexists: 'Word already exists' });
      } else {
        const newWord = new Word({
          user: req.user.id,
          ugrWordCyr: req.body.ugrWordCyr,
          ugrWordArb: req.body.ugrWordArb,
          rusTranslation: req.body.rusTranslation,
          origin: req.body.origin,
          sphere: req.body.sphere,
          lexis: req.body.lexis,
          grammar: req.body.grammar,
          partOfSpeech: req.body.partOfSpeech,
          style: req.body.style
        });
        // Social
        newWord.examples = [];
        /* if (req.body.exCyr) newWord.examples.exCyr = req.body.exCyr;
        if (req.body.trRus) newWord.examples.trRus = req.body.trRus;
        if (req.body.exLat) newWord.examples.exLat = req.body.exLat;
        if (req.body.trEng) newWord.examples.trEng = req.body.trEng;
        if (req.body.exArab) newWord.examples.exArab = req.body.exArab; */
        newWord.examples.push({
          exArab:req.body.exArab,
          trRus:req.body.trRus,
          exLat:req.body.exLat,
          trEng:req.body.trEng,
          exArab:req.body.exArab
        })
        newWord.save().then(word => {
          //now update user model
          User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id })
            .then(foundUser => {
              foundUser.score = foundUser.score + 150;
              foundUser
                .save()
                .then(savedUser => {
                  res.json({ word, savedUser });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'could not add score' });
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              return res.status(400).json({ error: 'could not find user' });
            });
        });
      }
    });
  }
);
```

What am I doing wrong? In front end it is all right!

Comment: Could you please share any error message, or what exactly is not working?

Comment: There is no a particular error, when i check my mongolab cloud, examples array is just empty.

Comment: What does `Word.find({})` return?

Comment: It returns all words that exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correct solution. No need to push anything into array.

```
const newWord = new Word({
              user: req.user.id,
              ugrWordCyr: req.body.ugrWordCyr,
              ugrWordArb: req.body.ugrWordArb,
              rusTranslation: req.body.rusTranslation,
              origin: req.body.origin,
              sphere: req.body.sphere,
              lexis: req.body.lexis,
              grammar: req.body.grammar,
              partOfSpeech: req.body.partOfSpeech,
              style: req.body.style,
              examples: req.body.examples
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are trying to push onto an array that doesn't exist yet on the `Model` instance.

Either add the empty array to the `Model` instance when you create it or save the model twice. After creating the empty array and then after pushing onto it.

Try this:

```
const newWord = new Word({
          user: req.user.id,
          ugrWordCyr: req.body.ugrWordCyr,
          ugrWordArb: req.body.ugrWordArb,
          rusTranslation: req.body.rusTranslation,
          origin: req.body.origin,
          sphere: req.body.sphere,
          lexis: req.body.lexis,
          grammar: req.body.grammar,
          partOfSpeech: req.body.partOfSpeech,
          style: req.body.style,
          examples: []; //add it here
        });
```

or this:

```
        newWord.examples = [];

        newWord.save().then(word => {
        // now push into the added array and then save again
        newWord.examples.push({
          exArab:req.body.exArab,
          trRus:req.body.trRus,
          exLat:req.body.exLat,
          trEng:req.body.trEng,
          exArab:req.body.exArab
        })
```

Comment: Hi @Travis James, I have tried your solution, but the examples array is still empty. Don't know why I tried both your suggestions.